# Which is correct, 经验非常丰富or 非常经验丰富？

Tags: grammar

I heard a TV host said in his comment that 他是一个非常经验丰富的队员, but which sounds weird, perhaps he wanted to say 他是一个经验非常丰富的队员? Which is correct or accpetable?

Comment: I agree with you; it sounds weird.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are correct. In grammar，经验非常丰富 means （拥有）非常丰富(的)经验. We usually use a Noun+Adjective to express [Noun] is [Adjective].

The TV host is wrong in fact. We should say 他是一个非常有经验的队员/他是一个经验丰富的队员, but can not say 一个非常经验丰富的队员. Howerver, chinese would understand his informal expression casuse we just take it as an error in speak. May be he wanted to say 非常有经验, and suddenly associated 经验丰富, so...

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. In some circumstances, especially in live shows, it could easily make mistakes in spoken, but people might tolerate most of them except those that totally could not be understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you divide that sentence up into 他是一个非常 and 经验丰富的队员 and consider the 经验丰富 an adjective it might make a little more sense. You could most definitely say 一个经验（很）丰富的队员 and perhaps adding the 非常 to precede that seems a little odd at first as in western languages we wouldn't really consider 经验丰富 an adjective if translated literally, however in this sentence you could almost say that it acts like one. While it might not be "grammatically correct" and you likely wouldn't see it written in a news paper or used in any other formal setting, in my experience it's not an uncommon way to phrase it colloquially.

Hope that made enough sense.